# Xamarin.Forms - Picker selected Item binding not responding

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I am making simple mvvm binding with `picker` field in xamarin.forms. I am following this guide [xamarin guide setting a picker's bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource/)

So I made a model:

```
public class Operation
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

An ViewModel:

```
private List<Operation> _operations;
public List<Operation> Operations
{
    get { return _operations; }
    set
    {
        _operations = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and View:

```
<Picker 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Number}"
    SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedOperation}"/>
<Entry x:Name="HelpEntry"
       Text="{Binding SelectedOperation.Name}" />
```

In the Pickers list items are displayed correctly, but when I Select an item number, then binding inside a Entry is not displayed.

Ouestion is, what am I doing wrong?

---

By the way.. I am doing this because I need to get an selected `Operation's Name` as variable in my code-behind section, by using HelpEntry.Text. It's not a smartest way and do u have better idea to do that?

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: First of all use an `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. Does the setter of the `SelectedOperation` call the `OnPropertyChange` method?

Comment: .. I didn't even made a variable inside view model. Everything is working perfectly now. It would be accepted answer. Thanks Alex!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ViewModel should also contain the `SelectedOperation` property that should also call the `OnPropertyChanged` method in its setter.

Also you should consider using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` in you view models.

Comment: ObservableCollection  not neccessary if it is only 1 time binding. you should only use ObservableCollection  if you change the list after first binding

Comment: @batmaci that's indeed true, i didn't say that he must use `ObservableCollection`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your ViewModel implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. The way to do this easily is to create a BaseViewModel that implements the interface and then inherit all of your concrete view model classes from this base class.

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class MainPageVM : ViewModelBase
{...}
```